# Size SwiftUI Image to adjacent Text

Tags: swiftui

I have Image, Text and HStack views as below.

```
HStack {
    Image("image")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()

        Text("Abc")
            .background(Color.red)
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(Color.green)
```

The image is quite a bit bigger than the text, but I want the  image to size itself to the text. Unfortunately, the image becomes its actual size:

```
.---------------HStack------------------
| .-----------.
| |           | .-----.
| |   Image   | | Abc |
| |           | `-----'
| `-----------'
`---------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Label, but if the image size is too large, you still need to resize the image and give it a frame size.
[image]